# How to get an array of xml attribute value using nokogiri in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nokogiri

I am writing tests in rspec rails.

My view has something like

```
<div id = "dataDiv" data-items= "[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]" data-check= "check">
```

I need to test the data of this division and used xpath for this.

In my specs,

```
it should have_xpath('//div[@id="dataDiv"][@data-check="check"]')
```

works fine but

```
it should have_xpath('//div[@id="dataDiv"][@data-items="[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]"]')
```

throws error saying "nil can't be converted to string".

I tried the following to get the attribute value

```
find.xpath('//div[@id="dataDiv"]/@data-items')
```

but that gives the same error as above. But I do have `@data-items` when I see in browser.

I am using rails 3.1 and nokogiri 1.4.4

Could anyone help me how to get this as array ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a quoting problem in your HTML so your HTML is invalid. You can't put raw double quotes inside a double-quoted attribute:

```
data-items="[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]"
```

That `data-items` is not a valid HTML attribute so I'm not surprised that Nokogiri can't understand it.

Try fixing your view to produce valid HTML:

```
data-items="[['A',100],['B',200],['C',50]]"
data-items='[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]'
```

and then update your XPath to match the inner quoting you use.

Furthermore, this part of your XPath suffers similar quoting problems:

```
[@data-items="[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]"]
```

so you need to fix that too:

```
have_xpath(%q{//div[@id="dataDiv"][@data-items='[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]']})
have_xpath('//div[@id="dataDiv"][@data-items=\'[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]\']')
```

or some other variant of the same idea.

Comment: Custom data attibutes are allowed in html and can be parsed using javascript on the client-side.data-check works fine as I mentioned in my question. The array is coming from my ruby code.So I can not modify the quotes.

Comment: @Studdy: Yes, HTML5 allows custom `data-` attributes but your `data-items` attribute is not valid HTML5 because you're trying to put double quotes inside a double quoted attribute value, `data-a="""` is not an HTML5 attribute and neither is your `data-items`; `data-check="check"` works fine because `"check"` is a valid attribute value but `"[["A",100],["B",200],["C",50]]"` is not. Your XPath expression suffers similar quoting problems. Fix your XPath, fix your HTML, and fix your Ruby.